# Targus USB-to-RS232 not working with Linux?

Tags: linux, usb, adapter, rs232

I have the Targus PA088 USB to RS232 converter, but it seems that it does not work with linux. Its RX and TX lights are flashing, but I can't see the data in minicom/picocom. When using it with Windows and hterm, everything's fine.

**Any idea what could be the problem?**

Additional info: When I plug in the adapter, I can see the following messages in /var/log/messages.log

```
Nov 25 01:47:31 localhost kernel: [  831.787066] usb 2-1.1: new full speed USB device number 5 using ehci_hcd
Nov 25 01:47:32 localhost kernel: [  832.554810] mct_u232 2-1.1:1.0: MCT U232 converter detected
Nov 25 01:47:32 localhost kernel: [  832.555002] usb 2-1.1: MCT U232 converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Nov 25 01:47:32 localhost mtp-probe: checking bus 2, device 5: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.1"
Nov 25 01:47:32 localhost mtp-probe: bus: 2, device: 5 was not an MTP device
```

Comment: Is this supported under Linux?  Do not see any support listed on teh site.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, you just don't have the terminal program you are using correctly configured for the parameters of the device you're talking to. The USB adapter is being correctly detected and mapped to `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Make sure your terminal program is using `/dev/ttyUSB0`. Also, make sure the baud rate, flow control, stop bits, and parity settings match what the device requires.

Comment: No, the configuration looks good, I've already checked that.

Comment: Did you check to make sure you don't have DCD enabled?